# Android DialogFragment onResume Event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two dialog fragment windows. Parent Dialog Fragment window having a listview which having a button.that button calls to child dialog fragment window.

[image]

Child DF is called by using Adapter class

```
  holder.Details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(context);
            FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            CustomerEditDialog alertDialog = new CustomerEditDialog(context);
              alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
            }
         });
```

Child DF is used for editing some information and upload them to a server. What i want to know is how to update Parent listview after editing is done and child DF is dismiss.

I have used

> onResume

and

> OnPause

to reset adapters in the parent DF.
 But those methods are not executing correctly.

Comment: Is there any Listener to identify from parent Dialog Fragment that Child Dialog Fragment is closed? I have tried onresume and onPause. But they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved . But i dont know this solution is a best practice.

I changed the Parent Dialog Fragments listview in to

```
Public static ListView listView;
```

Then access it in child Dialog Fragment and set the adapter.

```
  CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                                    R.layout.list_item, rowItemsa);
                       //Some Code

                          ParentFragment.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is tightly coupled with activity.So onResume() and OnPause() will call with activity. Instead you can follow :

Step 1 : Use 1 Dialog fragment instead of 2. Use 2 Dialog in it

Step 2 : Create Parent Dialog using onCreateDialog.

Step 3 : Make adapter of listview as instance variable.

Step 4 : Create Child Dialog using OnItemClickListener of listview.

step 5 : update list item of parent dialog using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().